# iPhone 5 (4") bottom toolbar not responding

Tags: iphone-5

I'm trying to modify an app to work with the new iPhone 5, 4" screen.
I've added the new launch image, "Default-568h@2x.png".
After that everything seemed good. Middle portion of my views is resizing ok.

However I've noticed that in a view where I have a bottom toolbar, the buttons on the toolbar are unresponsive. It looks ok, but tapping buttons does nothing. Same code run in simulator with 3.5" screen works fine.

Any ideas?

This view is within a navigation controller. It consists of a table view and toolbar. The tableview is set to resize height.

Comment: Did you inspect the frames of the toolbar and its superview? One scenario where this happens is if the child view lies outside the bounds of its container superview. The child view (or the toolbar in your case) still gets displayed because the parent view is not cutting off the content outside its bounds. One easy way to inspect the entire hierarchy is to call the hidden `recursiveDescription` method on a view while debugging as in `po [someParentView recursiveDescription]`.

Comment: I think that is whats happening, but I don't understand why. Trying your suggestion, the size looks correct until I get up to UIWindow where it says 320x480. Everything below has 320x568.

Comment: Thank you so much Anurag, your comment led me to solving my similar issue.

Comment: check this link I solve my prob with this. :[button/tool  Event overlap ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501976/my-button-doesnt-detect-touch-events-on-iphone-retina-4-inch-simulator-but-w/16008891#16008891http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501976/my-button-doesnt-detect-touch-events-on-iphone-retina-4-inch-simulator-but-w/16008891#16008891

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had the same problem and noticed that my window.frame.size.height was still 480.0.

Solved this problem by enabling **Full Screen at Launch** for the **MainWindow.xib** file:

Steps:

1. Open **MainWindow.xib**
2. Select the **Window** element
3. Open the **Attributes Inspector**
4. Under **Window** section, enable **Full Screen at Launch**

Comment: how can I set this programetically ?

Comment: Awesome, that one checkbox man.. btw, someone asked to try this in code for equal effect doesn't seem to work -     mainWindow.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

Comment: Was banging my head for last two days with this. But thanks to you.. Finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solution to this problem :

1. If you are using MainWindow follow these steps :

   a. Select MainWindow.xib
   b. Select 'Full Screen at Launch' from Windows option available in Attributes Inspector.
2. If your application doesn't contain MainWindow then just add 'Self.View.Frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds' in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

I your project has MainWindow.xib then you must have to set all splash images in order to compatible you app for iPhone 5 display.

Answer (score 0):

My Project wasn't using MainWindow.xib. I added the following to `viewDidLoad` in View Controllers of all the screens:

```
self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

Comment: didn't work, figure out how to turn the flag on for your main window in IB.. solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
self.window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

in this method:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)options
```

in your `%your app name%AppDelegate.m` file