# My button doesn't detect touch events on iPhone (Retina 4-inch) simulator, but works in iPhone (Retina 3.5-inch) simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iphone-5

I'm getting my app ready for the iPhone 5 using the simulator and I've found a weird issue where a couple of my buttons, in one of my views, don't work in the iPhone (Retina 4-inch) simulator, but work fine in the iPhone (Retina 3.5-inch) simulator. The buttons simply don't do anything when they're tapped. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

I having a difficult time figuring out where to start with this one.  Any suggestions on where to start?

Thanks so much in advance for all your wisdom!

Comment: Just a guess, but did you check that no transparent views overlap the buttons? Maybe springs and struts did not do what you expected with the iPhone 5's screen resolution.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. In my case the bottom region (probably the extra .5inch) is not responsive. Tab bar buttons placed there won't work, trying to flick scroll a UITableView from that region also doesn't work. Are your buttons positioned in the bottom region as well?

Comment: @pennersr: did you try this? it didn't help me any, but hopefully it'll help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414817/iphone-5-4-bottom-toolbar-not-responding

Comment: Check your compression resistance ratios are set to value of 1000 each for vertical and horizontal so that buttons are truly on screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by another control overlapping my buttons due to the way the springs and struts were setup.  Adjusting the z-order of the buttons fixed the issue. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 32):

You need to edit your MainWindow.xib and enable "Full Screen at Launch".  For a more detailed explanation, see Apple's docs:

> Important: When creating your window in Interface Builder, it is
>   recommended that you enable the Full Screen at Launch option in the
>   attributes inspector. If this option is not enabled and your window is
>   smaller than the screen of the target device, touch events will not be
>   received by some of your views. This is because windows (like all
>   views) do not receive touch events outside of their bounds rectangle.
>   Because views are not clipped to the window’s bounds by default, the
>   views still appear visible but events do not reach them. Enabling the
>   Full Screen at Launch option ensures that the window is sized
>   appropriately for the current screen.

[Complete document from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html)

Comment: The tabbar in my app didn't action touch events on the 4".  This fixed it... thanks.

Comment: I can understand why Apple doesn't have "Wants Full Screen" checked on the rootViewController, however I can't figure out why "Full Screen at Launch" isn't checked by default now that they've changed the screen size.  I had a tabBar disabled in iOS 6.1 as well.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking for a solution for two days.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the solution was to set the size ("Simulated Metrics") to "Retina 4 Full Screen" for the MainWindow.xib. I did not need to alter the size of the other screens (they are still set to None). After changing the MainWindow.xib the bottom area becomes clickable again...

Comment: Be careful of doing this.  This will actually mask the problem as it only enables touch events on the full screen in the simulator.  On a real device, the touch events will still not work unless you enable the Full Screen at Launch option in your MainWindow.xib.  See my answer for a more complete explanation.

Comment: This does not work correctly, as it will only change the view size. Things may not resize correctly with on a 3.5 inch screen. The best option is to enable "Full Screen at Launch" for the main window.

Answer (score 4):

There are two solution to this problem :

If you are using MainWindow follow these steps :

**a.** Select `MainWindow.xib`.

**b.** Select `Full Screen at Launch` from Windows option available in Attributes Inspector.

If your application doesn't contain MainWindow then just add:

```
self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
```

in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my prob.

view .origin for 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen are different so, when writing common code for both we need to take care at giving `CGRectmake(x,y,w,h)`;

Set temp. diff background color of diff view so you can check if any view is overlapping or not, to fetch event in 4.0 inch.