# Button doesn't work on iPhone 5, works on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iphone-5

I have a very strange issue. I have no device specific code. I'm not even using autolayout since I'm targeting back to iOS 4.3. So I tested on my iPhone 4S, and everything was fine. Sent it out for beta testing, and iPhone 5 users reported that one of the two buttons on my sign in view (the sign in button, a relatively important one), didn't work. It's not even detecting a touch down (not changing colors). I fired up the simulator, and in the iPhone 5 simulator, NEITHER of the buttons worked.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? I'm happy to share any code you think might be relevant, but I don't even know where to start, as there is no device specific code, and it works perfectly fine on the 4S, and behaves differently on the 5 and still differently on the 5 simulator.

EDIT: Turns out a view was overlapping the buttons due to autosizing. Figured this out by changing the Size in the .xib to retina 4 inch.

Comment: Look at the list of Related questions to this question. Several probably answer your question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501976/my-button-doesnt-detect-touch-events-on-iphone-retina-4-inch-simulator-but-w?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678864/iphone-5-simulator-cannot-click-on-bottom-of-screen?rq=1

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the help.