# TouchesBegan not called below 480px

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, iphone-5

I just added iPhone 5 compatibility to my iPhone application. To do this, I added copies of every view with new iPhone 5 dimensions and made the initiation process of the view controller choose by the size of the screen. 
Unfortunately, the method touchesBegan:withEvent: is not called when the touch occurs under the 480 pixel line. When you move it to above the line, it is suddenly called. This has been bugging me for a while. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this [question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12501976/767730) and [question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12678864/767730). Most probably your window is not getting resized.

Comment: This is what solved it. The window I thought was being called up was the right size but the actual window that was being called up was a different window that I had created in the past and had the old dimensions. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to give some upvotes to original questions and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably a view in your responder chain that is only 480 px height. It might be the view itself or any parent.

There is a nice debugger for something like that: http://sparkinspector.com/ .. which shows the complete view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your MainWindow.xib file has "Full Screen at Launch" checked!