# Xcode 4.5 4 inch simulator not allowing "Move and Scale" controls to work

Tags: ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller, ios6, iphone-5

I am trying to update my application to work with the new iPhone 5. It uses an image picker that allows you to move and scale your image (allowsEditing = TRUE;). However when I run the app on the 4 inch simulator, and use the picker, I can move the image and scale it, but the default "Cancel" and "Choose" buttons at the bottom of the picker are un-responsive.

Any ideas why that might be?? App is running fine on my iPhone 4 running iOS 6

****SOLVED** - see link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12418714/1618071

Comment: It actually seems like any control on the bottom portion of the simulator is not responding