# UIToolbar not responding to touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

I'm having a similar problem as asked here: [UIToolbar at the bottom not working in Retina 4 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591611/uitoolbar-at-the-bottom-not-working-in-retina-4-simulator).
My UIToolbar is not responding to touch on my iPhone 4. The toolbar is visible and at the bottom of the screen. Only when I move it up it will respond to touches.
so far no solution has worked for me.I'm using a storyboard and I have tried
enabling `use full screen` on all viewcontrollers and putting `self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;`in all my `viewdidload` methods.

I've also tried placing `[window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];` in my appdelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem. I was initialising one of my VC's with the wrong frame size.