# Need assistance regarding 'not working bottom on iphone5'

Tags: ios

Yesterday I try to test my app on iphone 5 but bottom of my app is not responding. I searched this issue I found these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414817/iphone-5-4-bottom-toolbar-not-responding)

Setting window.xib to "full screen at launch is not working" i dont know why.

`self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;` and this is need to be done on every view.

even this is not working for me `self.window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;`

All i need is a global solution, don't want to set on every view of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Different `UIViewControllers` might demand different adjusts. Normally setting the Auto-Sizing on the Root `UIView` from a `UIViewController's` XIB to re-size on height works. But you should take care of each `UIView` independently... Some animations you might be doing, may rely on the total height of the UIView, so you should pay attention to that. I use this macro, to check what kind of device I am on:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

It was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices), answer.