# iPhone IBOutlet responds on 3.5" in simulator but not on 4" / device

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uitoolbar, iboutlet

this one is a weird one, I'm updating the last of my old apps for the new 4" iphone screen.

I'm finding that a bottom uitoolbar with two segmented controls respond to user interaction in the 3.5" simulator, but when I build & run it on my 4" screen & simulator nothing happens.

NO view is on top of that (I actually even added bringSubviewToFront on ViewWillAppear just to make sure)

As it's responding on the 3.5 simulator I know is not an IBOutlet connectivity problem.

I baffled to say the least, has anyone run into this when updating your apps?

Comment: What is your `UIWindow`'s frame in `UIApplicationDelegate`?

Comment: Thank you man! really forgot that I had made a utility class for this! I have been moving towards android lately. if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `UIWindow`'s frame size in `UIApplicationDelegate`, may be its size is smaller (conforms to iPhone 4), you need to resize it to the new screen size of iPhone 5.

Have a look at this post too, may be its helpful for you:

[iPhone 5 (4") bottom toolbar not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12414817/593709)

Comment: oh, it was an oversight, I had already fixed 6 other apps but have spent the past 2 months just in android, it's one of those things one tends to forget. But THANK YOU for helping me out on this one